# Is it possible to add wildcard serveralias to virtualhost without modifying httpd.conf manually?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, a-record, serveralias

Is it possible to add wildcard serveralias (example: `*.somesite.com`) in an apache server without modifying httpd.conf manually? I use a DNS different from my hosting server and i have added asterisk A record to my DNS to point all request like (`test.somesite.com`,`test2.somesite.com`) to my hosting servers IP, but i don't see anyway of adding asterisk serveraliases to apache httpd.conf file in my cpanel. Pls is there a solution?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't manage this virtual host directly, outside of cpanel?

Comment: yes, i'm on a shared hosting server and i don't have direct access to httpd.conf file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of shared web hosting by an end-user or reseller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no solution if you do not have access to `httpd.conf`.

The reason is that is where Apache checks every time it gets a request - it is not delegated elsewhere. If it fails to find a match, it will give up, and return a default page. There is no way to work around this, I'm afraid.

On the other hand, many hosts are more than willing to make such a small change to their `httpd.conf`s for you. If they're not, you should really switch host.

Answer (score 0):

For the domain names format this will help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System
and this may help you achieve the automation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803263/automating-apache-virtual-hosts